# Goland IDE complains about builtin types

Tags: goland

I have a project which is intended to have completely own environment. That means:

1. The Go language compiler and tools are installed inside the project's folder (in `.deps\go` subfolder).
2. Similarly, the project has own GOPATH folder.
3. Also, this project uses the Go modules approach.

There is a special `build.cmd` file which sets GOROOT and GOPATH accordingly and builds the application. That cmd file works fine.

But, when I open the project in GoLand, it shows a lot of complains like "Unexported type usage" about all builtin types, such as `string`, `bool`, `float64`, etc.

This is a screenshot of how it looks like in GoLand
[image: This is a screenshot of how it looks like in GoLand]
When I Ctrl-click on the type name I'm getting to the `builtin.go` file inside the custom GOROOT, but it is shown with a lot of "Invalid recursive type" errors:
[image: A screenshot fo the <code>builtin.go</code> file]

The GOROOT and GOPATH settings in the Settings dialog are set accordingly (but there is another installation of the Go tools on the computer, if that does matter).
[image: Here are my settings on the GOPATH tab]

The question is: why GoLand produces those complains and what should I do to overcome them?

Comment: Instead of outbound links please add the images here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Go SDK is located inside the project so GoLand thinks that the user's files are inside. Excluding the `.deps` directory in *Preferences | Project Structure* should help.

[image]